# NetworkStatsManager.querySummaryForDevice; how to specify the start and end times properly to use an interval of 1 second?

Tags: android, networking, networkstatsmanager

I am attempting to collect second-by-second network usage, and the way to go seems like NetworkStatsManager. However, it collects summed data, whereas I'm looking for different network usage values second by second, so I can track to see how big of a jump occurs in usage when I use one app vs another app. I tried to set the start time as `System.currentTimeMillis()-(60*1000);` and the end time as `System.currentTimeMillis();` however this doesn't appear to do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At least for `queryDetails()`: "Since bucket length is in the order of hours, this method cannot be used to measure data usage on a fine grained time scale." I would not be the least bit surprised if you cannot get fine-grained details with `querySummaryForDevice()` either.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah, okay. The weird thing is that even though I can't display the change second-by-second, when I display the total second-by-second, I can see it changing when I use some sort of streaming app for example (so for example, it's not like the total stays static for a long time before it updates; it does change in real-time when I use apps). Would there be some way for me to calculate the real time change manually by keeping track of two total values and subtracting them?

Comment: The approach that you describe is pretty much what we have had to do with `TrafficStats` on prior versions of Android. I have no idea how accurate it is at the granularity that you are seeking.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, I've implemented essentially just getting and storing one value of wifi usage, waiting ~1 second, polling the wifi usage again to get another value, and subtracting the difference to get the change. Seems to work well enough, because I can see it change immediately when I start using apps that have network impact, like the YouTube app. Is the data 100% accurate? Who knows, but at least it's something.